# hibernate (MongoDB) throws InvocationException for string list despite @ElementCollection

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate

I try to get objects from MongoDB via org.hibernate.ogm and I get an exception for a List with strings. The exception is: *com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.*

The list is defined in the class as:

```
@ElementCollection
private List<String> myStringList;
```

I verified the document in the MongoDB and i can see the list there as array.

**FYI**: other attributes (primitive types) work fine in the class. Do you have any idea what's the problem? I checked the hibernate douments and there is described the implementation of the list with primitive types as i did it.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `@ElementCollection` for related entities not arrays of Strings?

You'll also need for entities collections to work:

```
 @CollectionTable(
        name="PHONE",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID")
  )
```